# How can I render a list of divs in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I am trying to render multiple divs at once. This function runs when the page is reloaded. (I have checked by logging the console). I don't get any errors, but the elements do not appear on the page. Could someone please help? Thanks!

```
const renderEvents = (day) => {
if (day == 0) {
  items.map(doc => {
    return (
      <div
        key={doc.id}
        className="item"
        style={createStyle(doc)}
      >
        <h3>{doc.data().title}</h3>
        <p>Start {doc.data().start.toDate().getHours()} End {doc.data().end.toDate().getHours()}</p>
      </div>
    )
  });
}
```

}

Edit: I tried returning from the renderEvents function but that didn't change anything:

```
const renderEvents = (day) => {
//if (day == 0) {
  return (items.map(doc => {
    return (
      <div
        key={doc.id}
        className="item"
        style={createStyle(doc)}
      >
        <h3>{doc.data().title}</h3>
        <p>Start {doc.data().start.toDate().getHours()} End {doc.data().end.toDate().getHours()}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }));
//}
```

}

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function. Maybe `return items.map...`? But make sure you return something if `day !== 0` too.

Comment: you aren't returning anything. either add `return` in front of items or remove the brackets around the component

Comment: I see a return inside of your map function, but nothing being returned by renderEvents

Comment: I tried returning from the renderEvents function but nothing changed.

Comment: where are you defining items? I don't see it getting passed in as a prop or anything

Comment: If you can at all help it, don't use divs but use proper semantic markup. These look like `<section>`, not `<div>`, or (given that the `<p>` content isn't very... real text) just `<li>` inside a `<ul>` with CSS to render the way you need it rendered.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a __[mcve]__, and be included in your question, along with supporting input values, and expected output.

Comment: After working on the problem a bit more, I have solved the problem. Items is undefined at the time I am calling the function (items is assigned values asynchronously). I realize my question was not as clear as I should have made it. I apologize for that. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Can you provide your complete implementation showing from.where you're getting items all that ? Then we can also identify where you went wrong.